# How to join datas from many different tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I have a very difficult task for me. I don't understand, which query I should write to display needed dates.
So, the task is to join different tables in one temporary table.
I have tables

[my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHzoQ.jpg)

So I want to get the patient's full name, his address, dob (date of birthday), his gender,  user's full name, status's name and diagnosis
How to do it? Can you attach the link with the theory ?

Comment: You should edit your question and show an attempt that you have made.  You should also provide sample data and desired results.  What do you want for patients that have more than one diagnosis, for instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an Example:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table2 AS (
    SELECT column_name(s)
    FROM table1
    INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.column_name = table2.column_name
    ....
    )
```

About Inner Join: [Link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

Creating a Temporary Table :[Link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html)

Answer (score 0):

I assume `dob` and `gender` refer to patient dob and gender.

```
SELECT task.ID, task.diagnosis, patient.name, patient.surname, patient.m_name, user.name, user.surname, user.m_name, status.name, patient.address, patient.dob, patient.gender 
FROM task
INNER JOIN user ON task.id_user=user.ID 
INNER JOIN patient ON task.id_patient = patient.ID
INNER JOIN status ON task.id_status = status.ID
```

Here is an example how to use [INNER JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp).

You can read more here: [JOIN Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)